# iPhone wifi connection log file?

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone, logs

I have an iPhone 5s with the latest version of iOS.  The wireless (and bluetooth) card has stopped working (tested at the Genius Bar) just a couple weeks out of warranty.  Apple wants $250+ to replace the phone.

I wonder if I can determine when the phone last connected to a wifi network?  If I can determine that it has not connected to my home wifi prior to expiration of the warranty, Apple may have an obligation to replace the phone without charge.

Does a log file exist (and if so where can I find it) that would show the information I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs are available via Xcode, however they are overwritten pretty quickly in order to prevent from consuming large amounts of memory on the device.  Usually you can only get a few days worth of logs at most.  That means that the logs you are seeking have certainly already been deleted from the device.  These are the same diagnostic logs that are available at the Genius bar.  They are useful for troubleshooting current issues, but they are not usefully for determining how long you have had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6876454?start=0&tstart=0) contains information about Wifi logs on iOS 8, but it has not changed since the release of iOS 9. Basically, you could see a history if you could actually connect to the network in question--i.e., your home network--but this will not help your situation since you cannot actually connect to the network. So, in your case, there is no way to see the lsat time you connected to your Wifi network.

Perhaps--and this is quite a stretch--you could make a Genius Bar appointment and have them run diagnostics. Tell them you are having Wifi issues, and tell them you don't know how long it's been going on. They may be able to show you the diagnostic logs. Then, armed with that information, if it has not connected since before the warranty ran out, you may have some luck with the same Genius.

~Good luck, and I hope this helps.

Comment: Any chance I could view the logs if I connect to iTunes?

Comment: No, because iTunes does not give any network information like Wifi. It gives very little system information about the device itself at all, so you won't be able to see it. It would be something that would only show up in diagnostics.